# Removing automatic numbering of chapters and the insert of chapter number into figure captions in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'm using bookdown to write a paper. The knitted word file automatically assigns numbers to each heading, to form chapters. However, I don't want these, as they're sections of a paper rather than individual chapters.

I have found if I include `{-}` next to a heading, it isn't given a number in the word output. However, the figures are still captioned as if they're numbered by chapters, but instead of being "Fig 1.2" they are Fig "0.2" and I actually just want "Fig 2". Does anyone know how to stop it from doing this?

Comment: Knitting to pdf or word?

Comment: Knitting to word